# How to get user-modify:read-write-plaintext-only behaviour in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser

Chrome/Safari support css:

-webkit-user-modify:read-write-plaintext-only , which can disable user paste rich text into a contenteditable div.

I do not know how to get it in firefox and IE.

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408028/html5-contenteditable-div-accept-only-plaintext/31627656#31627656 can to some part what you look for. My answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31627656/1711186 there uses javascript to mimic the plaintext only behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the -moz prefix for firefox

```
-moz-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
```

And for IE (10+) you can use the -ms prefix

```
-ms-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
```

It would also be proper to add it without the prefix for future proofing ;)

```
user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
```

Comment: Sorry, but you believe wrong. Firefox does not support this see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-modify

Comment: IE 11 does not support "-ms-user-modify" or "user-modify" styles either