# contenteditable v.s. user-modify

Tags: html, contenteditable

What are the major differences between the `contenteditable` attribute and the `user-modify` css rule?

So far I have spotted two:

1. Using `user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only` we can [disable pasting of rich text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484006/how-to-get-user-modifyread-write-plaintext-only-behaviour-in-firefox-and-ie).
2. `user-modify` is only supported in IE10+ while `contenteditable` is supported in IE since version 5.5

Thanks!

Comment: Too bad this doesn't have more answers. However it looks like you've listed most of the differences/benefits.

Comment: The first point is only hackishly true. It is not cross browser. Firefox for instance does not support it.

Answer (score 4):

One major difference is that via the CSS style one could according [to some W3C draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-modify)
have the following values:

> - read-only:  The user can view, select (if applicable) and copy information out of the element, but cannot modify the contents of the
>   element.
> - read-write:
>   The user can view, select (if applicable), and edit the contents of the element.
> - write-only:
>   The user can select and edit the contents of the element, but is unable to view the actual contents, nor copy them out. The rendering
>   of the "unreadable" content is user agent dependent (perhaps rendered
>   as nothing, a sequence of bullets or some other form of
>   text-greeking.)

this means that potentially one could set an element to be "write-only" which would (dependent to the implementation) be a state similar to the `'<input type="password".....>'` element.

In non-standard `-webkit` you can as mentioned make a plaintext only thing, not currently possible in Firefox (as mentioned by my comment above)

## update

Test with current 38 Firefox show that indeed the CSS property has no fact whatsoever on the content becoming editable. The only way seems to be via html-tag attribute contentediable.