# HTML5 contenteditable div accept only plaintext

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a **HTML5** contenteditable div, which only accept a plain text. I'm using html and jQuery below:

**HTML**

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
(function () {
   $('[contenteditable]').on('paste', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var text = null;
     text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain') || prompt('Paste Your Text Here');
     document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
   });
 });
```

But it's not working for all browsers. `getData` not support in Internet Explorer browser. I tried a lot of solutions mention here on stackoverflow, But none worked for me.

I also tried

```
(function () {
  $('[contenteditable]').on('paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = null;

    if (window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData) {
      text = window.clipboardData.getData('text');
    } else {
      text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain') || prompt('Paste Your Text Here');
    }
    document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
  });
});
```

But in that case `document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);` is not working for IE.

Is there any way to make it possible to accept data after filter HTML tags, So that anyone enters data in editable div by type, paste, drop, or any other way. It should display it as text.

Comment: Look at using this concept: `$('<p>Hi, I\'m <abbr title="Hypertext Markup Language">HTML</abbr></p>').text();`. That should give you `Hi, I'm HTML`.

Comment: I guess It's the different thing you are talking about. In our case we have to get pasted content. Convert it to plain text and than display it in div.

Comment: My comment covers the "convert it to plain text" part. I don't have any experience working with the JavaScript API for what you're trying to do, but as I read the question, I have trouble understanding what you're having trouble with. For example, is "_now_ working for IE" supposed to read as, "_not_ working for IE?"

Comment: Just add `contendeditable='plaintext-only'`

Comment: Unfortunately `contenteditable='plaintext-only'` seems to be a webkit-only feature.

Comment: Pasting is not the only way to get content into a contenteditable. Don't forget drag+drop, that completely circumvents checking for pasting.

Comment: `plaintext-only` might hopefully be standardized one day: https://github.com/w3c/editing/issues/162

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
<div contenteditable="plaintext-only"></div>
```

Reference: https://w3c.github.io/editing/contentEditable.html#h-contenteditable

Comment: Webkit only I guess. The spec only allow for true, false and inherit. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) (3 specs inside)

Comment: Reference link is broken now. "plaintext-only" should be a standard at this point but sadly isn't.

Answer (score 7):

Being not a big fan of jQuery, my solution will not make any use of it. Anyway here it goes (it should anyway work, as pure javascript):

```js
function convertToPlaintext() {
  var textContent = this.textContent;
  this.innerHTML = "";
  this.textContent = textContent;
}

var contentEditableNodes = document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable]');

[].forEach.call(contentEditableNodes, function(div) {
  div.addEventListener("input", convertToPlaintext, false);
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" style="border: dashed 1px grey">Editable</div>
```

Note that this solution is severely limited in that the caret will typically jump to the start of the text on every input event.

Comment: To fix the cursor issue you can use rangy: before: `let range = rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)` after: `if (el.hasChildNodes()) {
        newRange.setStart(el.childNodes[0], Math.min(range.startOffset));
        newRange.collapse(true);
        rangy.getSelection().setSingleRange(newRange);
      }`

Comment: An alternative is to only target the `paste` event

Answer (score 0):

In inspired by @humanityANDpeace answer, I came up with this:

```
function convertToPlaintext() {
  this.innerHTML = this.innerText.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
  this.focus();
  document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);
  document.getSelection().collapseToEnd();}
```

called by:

```
ele.addEventListener("input", convertToPlaintext, false);
```

where 'ele' is your contentEditable div.
This will replace any line breaks with `<br>` and keep the cursor at the end of text as you type.
My primary motive was to replace all div tags that 'contentEditable' adds but still retain line breaks.

The 'replace line breaks' came from:https://stackoverflow.com/a/784547/2677034